# Automatically clear message in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, alert

in CakePHP 3.7.7 I can show any Flash message in this way:

```
$this->Flash->error(__('Username or password is incorrect.'));
```

no matter the type of message (error, success, etc...) I want to automatically dismiss them after some time, if the user didn't before.

I searched in the documentation but it seems CakePHP lack such a feature (i.e. a timeout to be specified in the function call).
I guess I need to use js or jQuery to catch a new alert and then dismiss it after some time.

I'm not sure if this approach is feasible, though. And which selector I should use to find any alert in any page.

Comment: Yes, you'd need to use some additional JS. If you inspect the generated HTML, you'll see what classes are on the message that you might use as selectors; if there's nothing specific enough, you might edit your layout to wrap the entire Flash output in a `div` with a set ID that you could reference.

Comment: Good hint. I think if you would provide a minimal example your comment might become an good acceptable answer.

Comment: Anyway, it works fine, thanks!